# Run program as root using SUID

Tags: c, suid

Don't tell me this is a duplicate because I have already read questions like [how to execute a command as root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17822599/how-to-execute-a-command-as-root) but I just can't make it work for me.

This is my C program `whoami.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    system("whoami");
}
```

And this is exactly what I did:

```
user@ubuntu:~/Desktop/test$ ls
whoami.c
user@ubuntu:~/Desktop/test$ gcc whoami.c 
user@ubuntu:~/Desktop/test$ sudo chown root:root a.out 
[sudo] password for user: 
user@ubuntu:~/Desktop/test$ sudo chmod 4711 a.out 
user@ubuntu:~/Desktop/test$ ls -l
total 24
-rws--x--x 1 root    root    16816 Nov 13 13:03 a.out
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user    user    75    Nov 13 13:03 whoami.c
user@ubuntu:~/Desktop/test$ ./a.out 
user
user@ubuntu:~/Desktop/test$ sudo ./a.out 
root
user@ubuntu:~/Desktop/test$
```

I thought that the `s` in the execution bit means that no matter who starts this program, it will ever run as root so my question is why is this not working?

And if doing this is not possible how can I let any user run a specific program as root?

Comment: Read this: [**Unix / Linux: Difference between Real User ID, Effective User ID and Saved User ID**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32455684/unix-linux-difference-between-real-user-id-effective-user-id-and-saved-user)  And then read the `whoami` man page...

Comment: Also check that your volume is not mounted with `-nosuid`.

Comment: Just to be clear `whoami` is just an example I can't either reed root protected files using this same method, but I can do it adding `sudo` of course which is the normal behavior, SUID seams to be completely useless.

Comment: @Tommimon *SUID seams to be completely useless.*  And just how do you think `sudo` works?

Comment: I'm doing it right now, I was just saying don't focus on `whoami` because is an example

Comment: So using SUID I'm changing the effective ID right? And to read a file which one matters real or effective?

Comment: @n. 'pronouns' m. how can I check that?

Comment: No it' the other way around. You are changing real and you need effective. To change effective uid, call `setuid()` (see `man 2 setuid`). You can only do that if real uid is root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me: add `setuid(geteuid());` before running de command.

To use `setuid()` and `geteuid()` you need to import `unistd.h`

Working program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    setuid(geteuid());
    system("whoami");
}
```

If you set up SUID with the same commands of the question you get always `root` as output no matter which user run this program.

Instead of `whoami` you can use any other command, also if it require root privileges.

I saw this setup in a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iv5gflNM7rc)